# Prove or disprove a set function is a measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Given the sequence of finite measures $\left\{t_n\right\}$ on a measurable space $(A, M)$ with $\sup_{n\in N}\ t_n(A)<\infty$. Let $u: M\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be $u(E) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} t_n(E)$ for any $E\in M$. Prove or disprove that $u$ is a measure on $(A, M)$.

**My attempt:** It's easy to prove that $u(\emptyset) = 0$, and $u(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} E_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} u(E_i)$. What I'm wondering is whether the RHS does need to be convergent?? I don't think this is the case, because $u$ can take on $\infty$ from the definition of its range. Thus, $u$ **is** a measure.

Can someone please help check if this is a correct argument? Really appreciate your thought.

Comment: For every $E \in A$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} t_n(E)$ is convergent in $[0,\infty]$ since the sequence of partial sums $\left(\sum_{n=1}^N t_n(E)\right)_N$ is increasing, so $u$ is well-defined.

Comment: @Ahmed Hussein: Thanks for your comment. But $u$ can take on infinity, so why do we need the RHS to be convergent for $u$ to be well-defined though? Hmm..sequence of partial sums is increasing, so the series converge?? I don't think that's true, for example: if you have the sequence $\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n}$, then this sequence is increasing, but its series diverges since it's a harmonic series with $p=1$.

Comment: Well yes, that's convergence in $\Bbb R$, but the setting here takes place in $[0,\infty]$. Any increasing sequence is convergent because it is bounded above by $\infty$.

Comment: @AhmedHussein: thank you for your good point. Isn't that pretty much the same as saying "because u can take on infinity value, it doesn't matter in the case when the RHS approaches to infinity?"

Comment: I am glad I helped. What you are after is verifying whether or not $u$ is well-defined. To do that, you need to check that the RHS always makes sense to talk about, i.e. that the sum has a particular value in $[0,\infty]$ for each $E\in A$; this is the same as checking that the series is convergent in $[0,\infty]$. Note also that the RHS cannot "approach" infinity; it is a concrete value - i.e., if the series "diverges" to $\infty$, then the RHS is equal to $\infty$.